# Get path to JSON object by key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, lodash

Given the following object:

```
const ourObject = {
    "payload": {
        "streams": [
            {
                "children": {
                    "2165d20a-6276-468f-a02f-1abd65cad618": {
                        "additionalInformation": {
                            "narrative": {
                                "apple": "A",
                                "banana": "B"
                            },
                            "myInventory": {
                                "fruits": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "apple"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "banana"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

We're trying to find the path of `myInventory`, the issue is that the children's uuid will be different each time. Any idea how we can get the path to `myInventory` by providing it as a key and get the json path to it?

Comment: `streams` is an array, will it always have a single item ? And will `children` only have a single key inside it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If things are dynamic, a programmatic key search could help

```js
const ourObject = {
    "payload": {
        "streams": [
            {
                "children": {
                    "2165d20a-6276-468f-a02f-1abd65cad618": {
                        "additionalInformation": {
                            "narrative": {
                                "apple": "A",
                                "banana": "B"
                            },
                            "myInventory": {
                                "fruits": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "apple"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "banana"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};

const getPath = (key, o) => {
  if (!o || typeof o !== "object") {
    return "";
  }

  const keys = Object.keys(o);
  for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if (keys[i] === key ) {
      return key;
    }
    
    const path = getPath(key, o[keys[i]]);
    if (path) {
      return keys[i] + "." + path;
    }
  }
  return "";
};

const getValueForKey = (key, o) => {
  if (!o || typeof o !== "object") {
    return undefined;
  }

  const keys = Object.keys(o);
  for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if (keys[i] === key ) {
      return o[key];
    }
    
    const value = getValueForKey(key, o[keys[i]]);
    if (value) {
      return value;
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}

console.log(getPath("myInventory", ourObject))
console.log(getValueForKey("myInventory", ourObject))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question right but

```
let uuid = '2165d20a-6276-468f-a02f-1abd65cad618';
ourObject.payload.streams[0].children[uuid].additionalInformation.myInventory
```

Comment: The thing is the uuid is not going to be known each time, so how can we get to the myInventory based on just the key. For example using a wildcard won't work:
`ourObject.payload.streams[0].children[*].additionalInformation.myInventory`

Answer (score 0):

```
var changingKey = Object.keys(ourObject["payload"]["streams"][0]["children"])[0]; 

console.log(ourObject["payload"]["streams"][0]["children"][changingKey]["additionalInformation"]["myInventory"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you could create a helper function that gets the UUID. Since it's an object, the lookup is close to O(1) especially given the case that the children has only one key-value pair here.

```
function getUUIDFromPayload(payload) {
    let obj = payload.streams[0].children
    let uuid = Object.keys(obj)[0]
    return uuid
}
```

Usage

```
const uuid = getUUIDFromPayload(payload)
ourObject.payload.streams[0].children[uuid].additionalInformation.myInventory
```